# strange char array output in c++

Tags: c++

I met a strange problem.
In C++

```
char s[]="123abc89";
cout<<s[0]<<endl;  //1  it is right
cout<<&s[0]<<endl; // I can't understand why it is "123abc89"
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: a) don't use arrays (prefer std::vector/std::array) b) this is working as intended, the second one calls the `char*` overload for operator `<<` which prints the whole c-string.

Comment: Were you looking for the second to print the memory address, one character, or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`s[0]` is the 1st element of character array. `&s[0]` is the address of the 1st element, the same to the address of the array. Given the start address of a character array, `std::cout` prints out the whole string starting at that address, using the following [overload of operator<<](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/) :

```
// prints the c-style string whose starting address is "s"
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const char* s);
```

If you want to print the start address of the character array, one way is to:

```
// std::hex is optional. It prints the address in hexadecimal format.  
cout<< std::hex << static_cast<void*>(&s[0]) << std::endl;
```

This will instead use another [overload of operator<<](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) :

```
// prints the value of a pointer itself
ostream& operator<< (const void* val);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running into the internals of how C (and C++) handle strings (not std::string for C++).

A string is referenced by a pointer to it's first character.  Here's code that shows this:

```
char *ptr;

ptr = "hello\n";

printf("%s\n", ptr);
ptr++;
printf("%s\n", ptr);
```

Comment: Actually, to be more accurate - C has no built-in string construct.  This is a feature of the standard C library.

Comment: Ash: Simply not true, string literals are a built in construct, `argv` is defined to specifically contain "pointers to strings", the description of the character set says that the null character "is used to terminate a character string" etc etc.

Comment: The main function is called by the "C" startup code, which is in a library.

Comment: Doesn't even deserve a response.

Comment: Actuall, the "C" language is rather bare if you look at the core of it.  There no input nor output (open/read/write are function calls, not language statements).  Even the main function isn't part of the langauge itself.  They are probably part of some standards now that some might consider the same as "the C language"...

Comment: The C programming language is defined by the C standard, everyone considers it to define the C programming language, or they're just wrong.